# Do dynlm and dlm have same mathematical expressions?

Tags: r, regression, dynamic-regression

I am currently using dynamic linear regression (dynlm) for my analysis. However, I do also find another model called dynamic linear model (dlm).

I find that dlm has an official mathematical expression by West and Harrison (1989) and everywhere. 
However, I cannot find an official mathematical expression for dynlm elsewhere.
Even the official R program document verbally explains that it is just an extended version of linear regression that allows additional feature but with no explicit mathematical expression.

Can I assume the official mathematical expression for dynlm and dlm identical?
If not, may I know the official mathematical expression for dynlm in r programming?